# Kinds of the singular points for this function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Question) 
Let the entire function $f $ on $\mathbb{C}$ $s.t.$ $\vert f(z) \vert \leq \vert 
z^{2020} + z^{2019} + ... +1\vert$

Say $f(i)$ = $1 \over 2$$(e-1)$

Find the value of the $f(e)$

---

The above question lecturer gave to class and suggested his solution.

Let the $g(z) = {f(z) \over z^{2020} + z^{2019} + ... +1}$

And there are roots $\alpha_i,(1 \leq i \leq 2020  )$ of the $z^{2020} + z^{2019} + ... +1$

Hence $g(z)$ has a removable point at the $\alpha_i$.

So we can consider the entire function on $\mathbb{C}$ if we define the value of the each $\alpha_i$ as the each limit of them. So Next step is just applying Liouville's theorem. Let's call it a day

The things I've been said are his explanation and comment. But At least I thought Does the  $g(z)$ has Pole at $\alpha_i $? Plus We don't know the g(z) has some roots $\alpha_i$, Hence we can't conclude the it it removable, pole or not. What do you think? If his solution is incorrect, What is the correct solution?

Thanks.

Comment: If $\alpha_i$ is a root of $z^{2020}+\cdots+1$, then the given inequality says that $f(\alpha_i)=0$, hence all the $\alpha_i$'s are removable singularities of $g$. In fact, by Liouville's theorem, $f(z)=f(i)(z^{2020}+\cdots+1).$ The rest can be done by geometric series.

Comment: Err...I missed the inequality. Thanks for What I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(z)=z^{2020}+\cdots+z+1.$ Then by the periodic pattern of $i^k$, it is easy to see that $h(i)=1.$ Note that $$(z-1)h(z)=z^{2021}-1,$$ so $h(z)$ has simple roots consisting of roots of unity. Let $\alpha_i,1\leq i \leq 2020$, be the roots of $h(z)$. The the condition $|f(z)|\leq |h(z)|$ shows that $f(\alpha_i)=0$ for each $i$, and hence $f(z)$ can be factored as $$f(z)=g(z)h(z),$$ where $g(z)$ is entire. Now the condition $|f(z)|\leq |h(z)|$ says that $g(z)$ is bounded, hence a constant by Liouville's theorem. It follows that $f(i)=g(i)h(i)=g(i)=g(z)$ and hence $$f(z)=f(i)h(z).$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes. Dear Pythagoras. :) I took the result.